# Emails sent using SendGrid on Heroku Django app to @gmail.com addresses seem to be blocked

Tags: django, email, heroku, gmail, sendgrid

I have a django app on heroku an  using sendgrid.

I have gotten messages from a number of users with gmail email addresses saying that they have not received their validation emails after registering to use the site.

I tested it myself, and found that while emails with other addresses go through instantly, but for some gmail accounts it is not going through.

In the sendgrid dashboard, however, it says that all the emails have been delivered.

Can someone tell me what the issue here is? Is gmail blocking emails from my site? It just started happening these last two days. And we're not really sending out that many emails (10 or so a day)

Answer (score 0):

Do the Emails end up in a spam folder, or do they truly disappear?

What kind of plan are you on at SendGrid? If you have your own dedicated IP, have you followed the guidelines on 'warming up' that IP address? Might also want to review the content of the message with SendGrid support, see if they can make any recommendations.

Comment: I'm actually not receiving them at all. I'm on the basic free plan at Sendgrid. I'll send them an email and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

Emails end up in the spam folder. Whenever an email was sent from Heroku, Sendgrid to @gmail accounts, they were viewed as spam by Gmail.
I have the same problem and did not find a solution yet.